# Unable to POST request from React frontend served through nginx to node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I am hosting my express backend REST API and react frontend on the same linux server. I am serving the react build files on port 80 with nginx using `HTTP` protocol and the backend is run locally on port 1210 in the remote server using pm2.

The build files from react are inside `/var/www/agpcms/html/` folder. Nginx configurations are `/etc/nginx/sites-available/agpcms` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/agpcms`.

```
# in /etc/nginx/sites-available/agpcms
server {
  listen 80;
  
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/agpcms/html;
  index index.html;
  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/agpcms.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/agpcms.com.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off; 
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I can perform GET requests fine but upon sending POST requests like signing up, I cannot get a response from the backend. I have tried commenting/uncommenting  the nginx config file above but no luck so far. The error I got on browser tools

On Brave browser (Chromium), I get `(failed)` status from both `xhr` and `preflight` requests.
On Firefox, both OPTIONS and POST requests return empty responses and prints this to the console

```
on Firefox console
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1210/apis/v1/auth/signup. 
(Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). [Learn more]
```

I am positive that I have set up CORS correctly as I have tried with GET requests on the backend from the browser by exposing port 1210.

What am I missing here to make it able to handle POST requests? I am currently not setting up https but will I need to run this in https so as to resolve this?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to build the front end using the IP address of the remote server i.e. `x.xx.xx.xxx`, not `localhost`, and also change the `server_name` to this IP address. This solved my problem.